# Can Python actually print large strings faster than C++?

Tags: c++, performance, printing, io

I am a student who is quite new to C++ and I wanted to code something to get used to this language. A while ago, I coded a Python program that makes ASCII art "videos". Basically, it converts every frame of the video to strings that are stored in a list, and then displays them on the terminal. But the computations were way too slow, so I decided to switch to C++. In the end, I managed to speed up the conversion process by a lot just by switching to C++.

However, as I tried to print the ASCII frames on the terminal, I noticed that there was a weird stuttering problem that didn't occur with Python (see link):
[Video link](https://streamable.com/ndhmh0)

Here is the C++ code snippet that handles the printing.

```
(...)

    auto start_time(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now());
    int current_index(0);
    int last_index(0);

    while (current_index < number_of_frames - 1) {
        // Computing the current index
        double elapsed_time(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_time).count() / 1000.);
        double percentage(elapsed_time / audio_duration);
        current_index = percentage * number_of_frames;

        // Print the new frame if it's different from the last one to avoid spamming them
        if (current_index != last_index) {
            _write(_fileno(stdout), frames[current_index].c_str(), frames[current_index].size());
        }
        last_index = current_index;
    }

(...)
```

In order to compare it with Python, here is the Python version of that piece of code. It uses the `time` and `sys` modules.

```
(...)

start_time = time.time()

current_frame = 0  # nombre de frames passées
last_frame = 0

while current_frame < len(frames) - 1:

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    percentage = (elapsed_time / float(audio_duration))
    current_frame = int(percentage * number_of_frames)

    if current_frame != last_frame:
        sys.stdout.write(frames[current_frame])
    last_frame = current_frame

(...)
```

While it may seem like a very specific question, it just didn't make any sense for Python to work better than C++ in this situation. Google didn't help either, so there must be a problem somewhere in my source code.

I tried calling different types of functions like `std::cout`, `std::prinf` and the raw `write` and even messing a bit with the frame data like resizing some of them but to no avail. I really don't know what is causing this issue.

Here are some steps to reproduce the issue in C++ (pseudocode/general outline):

1. Create a vector of strings. The strings must be of length `terminal_height*terminal_width` to cover your whole screen. It can be anything, but I recommend an easily identifiable pattern like ASCII art.
2. Iterate through the strings of that vector and print them on your terminal. The printing rate here doesn't seem to matter. I tested the rates with 15 -> 30 strings printed per second and the outcome seemed to be the same.
3. Set your terminal to full screen and run your program.

Here is the full C++ code. It uses OpenCV and FFmpeg. I did not try to optimise anything yet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <io.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>

#pragma comment (lib, "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;
namespace fs = filesystem;

// Prototypes
size_t number_of_files(fs::path path);

int main()
{
    // Defining the grey scale ramp
    string char_ramp("$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,\" ^ `'. ");
    reverse(char_ramp.begin(), char_ramp.end());

    
    // Ask user for input about the video
    string video_name("");
    int brightness(0);
    cout << "Mettez le terminal en plein ecran." << endl;
    cout << "Nom de la video et seuil de luminosite : ";
    cin >> video_name >> brightness;

    // Get terminal info
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
    const unsigned int target_frame_width(csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1);
    const unsigned int target_frame_height(csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1);
    // Get video and audio path
    const string video_path("videos/" + video_name);
    const string audio_path("tmp/audio.wav");

    cout << "[1/3] Nettoyage..." << endl;
    // Delete previous folders and make new ones for the new video
    fs::remove_all(audio_path);
    fs::remove_all("tmp/frames");
    fs::create_directory("tmp/frames");

    cout << "[2/3] Extraction des images et de l'audio..." << endl;
    // Ffmpeg extracts frames and audio
    system(("ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i " + video_path + " -vf scale=" + to_string(target_frame_width) + ":" + to_string(target_frame_height) + " tmp/frames/%0d.bmp").c_str());
    system(("ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i " + video_path + " tmp/audio.wav").c_str());

    cout << "[3/3] Conversion..." << endl;
    const size_t number_of_frames(number_of_files("tmp/frames"));
    vector<string> frames(number_of_frames);
    // Frame to ASCII frame conversion
    for (int frame_index(1); frame_index <= number_of_frames; ++frame_index) {
        string frame_path("tmp/frames/" + to_string(frame_index) + ".bmp");
        string current_frame("");
        cv::Mat current_bmp(cv::imread(frame_path));
        for (int i(0); i < current_bmp.rows; ++i) {
            for (int j(0); j < current_bmp.cols; ++j) {
                // Le vecteur des couleurs B, G, R du pixel (i, j)
                cv::Vec3b bgr(current_bmp.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j));
                // On utilise la luminance
                double greyscale_index(sqrt(0.299*bgr[2]*bgr[2] + 0.587*bgr[1]*bgr[1] + 0.114*bgr[0] *bgr[0]));
                current_frame += char_ramp[(int)(greyscale_index / 255 * (char_ramp.size() - 1)) / brightness];
            }
            current_frame += "\n";
        }
        frames[frame_index - 1] = current_frame;
    }
    // Grabbing audio duration
    FILE* fp;
    char var[40];
    double audio_duration(0);

    fp = _popen(("ffprobe -loglevel warning -i " + audio_path + " -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv=\"p=0\"").c_str(), "r");
    while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL) {
        audio_duration = atof(var);
    }
    _pclose(fp);

    PlaySound(TEXT("E:/Programmation/Cpp/SeuillageImage/tmp/audio.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC | SND_LOOP);

    // Begin printing frames
    auto start_time(chrono::steady_clock::now());
    int current_index(0);
    int last_index(0);

    while (current_index < number_of_frames - 1) {
        // Computing the current index
        double elapsed_time(chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::steady_clock::now() - start_time).count() / 1000.);
        double percentage(elapsed_time / audio_duration);
        current_index = percentage * number_of_frames;

        // Print the new frame if it's different from the last one to avoid spamming them
        if (current_index != last_index) {
            _write(_fileno(stdout), frames[current_index].c_str(), frames[current_index].size());
        }
        last_index = current_index;
    }

    // Stop audio
    PlaySound(NULL, NULL, 0);

    return 0;
}

size_t number_of_files(fs::path path) {
    return distance(fs::directory_iterator(path), fs::directory_iterator{});
}
```

Here is the Python version of that code. It uses the Python Imaging Library (`PIL`) and an optional `progress.bar` module. It is much slower than the C++ code.

```
import argparse
import os
import shutil
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import wave
import winsound
from math import sqrt

from PIL import Image
from progress.bar import IncrementalBar

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("video_name", type=str, help="Nom de la vidéo")
parser.add_argument("brightness", type=int, help="Seuil de luminosité")
arguments = parser.parse_args()

# http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/asciiart/
# "Standard" character ramp for grey scale pictures from black to white
char_ramp = """$@B%8&WM#*oahkbdpqwmZO0QLCJUYXzcvunxrjft/\|()1{}[]?-_+~<>i!lI;:,"^`'. """[::-1]

video_name = arguments.video_name
brightness = arguments.brightness
video_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fr"videos\{video_name}")
audio_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fr"tmp\audio.wav")

# ÉTAPE 1 : On supprime les fichiers déjà existants
print("[INFO] Étape 1 sur 3 : nettoyage...")
# On vérifie s'il existe déjà un dossier de stockage temporaire
if os.path.isdir("tmp"):
    # On supprime le dossier contenant les images de la vidéo et on en crée un nouveau
    if os.path.isdir("tmp/frames"):
        shutil.rmtree("tmp/frames", ignore_errors=False)
        os.mkdir("tmp/frames")
    # Idem pour le fichier audio correspondant
    if os.path.isfile("tmp/audio.wav"):
        os.remove("tmp/audio.wav")

# Sinon, on crée un nouveau dossier de stockage temporaire
else:
    os.mkdir("tmp")
    os.mkdir("tmp/frames")

# ÉTAPE 2 : On extrait les images successives de la vidéo avec ffmpeg une par une pour les convertir
print("[INFO] Étape 2 sur 3 : extraction des images et de l'audio...")
# On définit la longueur et la largeur de la fenêtre d'exécution
window_size = os.get_terminal_size()
target_frame_width = window_size[0] - 1
target_frame_height = window_size[1]

# On utilise le module externe ffmpeg pour extraire les images successives de la vidéo
subprocess.call(
    f"ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i {video_path} -vf scale={target_frame_width}:{target_frame_height} tmp/frames/%0d.bmp")
subprocess.call(f"ffmpeg -loglevel warning -i {video_path} tmp/audio.wav")

# ÉTAPE 3 : On convertit la vidéo en ASCII
print("[INFO] Étape 3 sur 3 : conversion de la vidéo en cours, cela peut prendre un certain temps...")
# On crée une liste dans laquelle on stocke les images et quelques autres variables utiles
frames = []
number_of_frames = len(
    [frame for frame in os.listdir("tmp/frames") if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("tmp/frames", frame))])
bar = IncrementalBar("Progression", max=number_of_frames)

for frame_index in range(1, number_of_frames + 1):
    frame_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), fr"tmp\frames\{frame_index}.bmp")
    # On construit l'image ASCII à partir de niveaux de gris dans l'image bitmap redimensionnée obtenue
    frame_builder = ""
    with Image.open(frame_path) as frame:
        # Pour chaque pixel de l'image
        for y in range(frame.height):
            for x in range(frame.width):
                # Conversion de chaque pixel en niveau de gris
                rgb = frame.getpixel((x, y))
                # On utilise la luminance plutôt que la moyenne RGB
                greyscale_index = sqrt(0.299 * rgb[0] ** 2 + 0.587 * rgb[1] ** 2 + 0.114 * rgb[2] ** 2)
                # On ajoute le caractère ASCII à la chaine une fois identifié (mapping linéaire)
                frame_builder += char_ramp[int(greyscale_index / 255 * (len(char_ramp) - 1)) // brightness]
            # On revient à la ligne pour chaque ligne traitée
            frame_builder += "\n"
    # On ajoute l'image Ascii crée à la liste des images de la vidéo
    frames.append(frame_builder)
    bar.next()
bar.finish()

# On initialise les fichiers audio et vidéo pour des calculs de fréquence
audio_wave = wave.open(audio_path, "rb")
audio_sample_rate = audio_wave.getframerate()
audio_frames = audio_wave.getnframes()
audio_duration = audio_frames / audio_sample_rate

# On joue la musique et on lance le chrono
winsound.PlaySound(audio_path, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
start_time = time.time()

# On imprime les frames en fonction de leur position dans le temps par rapport à l'audio (synchronisation)
current_frame = 0  # nombre de frames passées
last_frame = 0
while current_frame < len(frames) - 1:

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    percentage = (elapsed_time / float(audio_duration))
    current_frame = int(percentage * number_of_frames)

    if current_frame != last_frame:
        sys.stdout.write(frames[current_frame])
    last_frame = current_frame
```

I hope that this extra information can help you understand my problem better.

Comment: `chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` is not a good way to measure the time. You should use a `steady_clock` for wall-clock timings. The link you provide is not publicly available : it requires a google account. The use of such links is strongly discouraged on stack overflow.

Comment: *"it didn't make any sense for Python to work better than C++"* Not so much here since the operation is expected to be IO-bound and not compute bound. Python is actually not bad for IO stuff (especially since most of the time is spent in optimized low-level C functions of the interpreter and not Python code). I expect the performance of your code to be mainly affected by flush timings, syscalls and your terminal. Maybe Python use bigger buffers. What are the timings when the output is redirected to `/dev/null`? Please also share the python code in the question (so it can be self-contained).

Comment: Most people don't download stuff from the Google Drives of random strangers.

Comment: questions about performance issues need even more information than usual. First of all a [mcve] is required. Then we need to know how you build it. Optimizations turned on?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Hello, I included some changes in my original post. I shared the original source code in both C++ and Python languages and I provided a way for you to repdroduce the issue. I also changed the high resolution clock to a steady clock. Also what do you mean by the "timings when the output is redirected to `/dev/null` ?" I am still in the process of learning this kind of stuff. Can you specify what kind of time/duration you want to know?
I also added a link to the video that should work now.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed that you was on Linux, hence the `/dev/null` (which is Linux specific). Windows IOs are painfully slow (certainly because of the DOS emulation, still in 2023). IDK what `_write` is on Windows, but if it makes a syscall, then it will be slow. On Python, I expect the operation to be fully buffered and only few syscalls to be done. You should control the buffering and flushes in order to reduce the kind of "vsync" issue visible in your video. This is also needed in Python since the output must be flushed at the and of a frame (otherwise it could be every >10 frames).

Comment: I expect CPython to use the libc and so [`fwrite`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwrite) to behave similarly in C++ (using an internal buffer which is likely the one of the libc). Different compilers can have different performance since the libc used by CPython might not be the same than the one you use for your application. The buffer size can also be tuned and IDK if CPython tune it for sake of performance.

Comment: 1) Are you compiling your C++ code with the compilers optimizer *enabled*? 2) sounds like you are basically reimplementing [AALib](https://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/).

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hello, I ran my program in release mode to make sure that the code was being optimised by my compiler but I still have that "vsync" like problem. Are you suggesting I should install AALib for my program?

Comment: Update: I installed Windows Terminal and it seems to be fine? Cmd is just not optimised for character rendering it seems.

Comment: Cmd emulate an (obsolete) DOS console which is extremely slow as stated above. But as said previously, controlling flushes can mitigate performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, cmd.exe is too slow for my program. I switched to [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) and it worked perfectly fine. I also had to adjust the cursor's position so that it stays at (0, 0) to prevent the screen from scrolling.